# ¿ cómo crear el instalador combinando ClickOnce con el instalador tradicional para tener las actualizaciones automáticas?

Tags: c#

cómo crear el instalador combinando ClickOnce con el instalador tradicional para tener las actualizaciones automáticas

Comment: Aqui hay [un post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ed4f13a-fea4-4a5c-b388-801cabdd339b/combining-clickonce-and-msi-installer?forum=winformssetup) en un foro de MSDN